# javascript function,after complete writing is not working

Tags: javascript, html

**My requirement**:

I have a code which calculate **age** from **date of birth**.

**What I have done/ my code link**

[Click here for code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPxKWY)
It will only work in google chrome..not in firefox/other browsers..

**What I want?**: after complete `date of birth`, automatically calculate the age then, will show the proper age.And if the age `less than 18 or greater than 150` then it will show an alert.

**Problem Facing:**
In Google chrome,Before complete date of birth, an alert showing message.

where is the problem?

Comment: Please add your code to the post.

Comment: Temmu, I already have posted my code.. click the link

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to check for 4 digits:

After this:

```
day_age = day_age % 30;
```

Add this:

```
if(yearThen.toString().length != 4){ return false;}
```